# How to close a specific folder with VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a simple program with VBScript that closes a specific folder every time it gets opened, thus denying access to that folder. I've successfully used this code right here for many folders, but for some reason it doesn't work with `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp`.

```
Do
    WindowTitle = "FOLDERNAME"
    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    success = shell.AppActivate(WindowTitle)
    If success Then shell.SendKeys "%{F4}" 
Loop
```

Is there any way that I can deny access to that specific folder using .vbs files?

Comment: If you want to deny access to a folder do it the right way by adjusting the folder permissions.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I want to make it using a .vbs script instead,without touching any folder permissions. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"I want to make it using a .vbs script instead"* No you don't. Trust me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
myfolder = "C:\temp"
Set sh = CreateObject("shell.application")
For Each w In sh.Windows
    If w.document.folder.self.Path = myfolder Then w.Quit
Next
```

And here is a complete example to close your temporary folder :

```
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF &_
    CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else
Dim MyFolder,ws
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Myfolder = ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%temp%")
Do
    Call CloseThis(MyFolder)
    wscript.sleep 1000
Loop
End If
'*********************************************************************************************
Sub CloseThis(Folder)
Dim sh,w
Set sh = CreateObject("shell.application")
For Each w In sh.Windows
    If w.document.folder.self.Path = Folder Then w.Quit
Next
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function    
'*********************************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'*********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: Thanks! I have two questions about it though : First: Does the first code have to be used in conjunction with the second? and In the first code do I simply paste the entire path to my folder in the "myfolder"?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The first code is called as sub routine in second code. And just replace the variable `myfolder` to yours

Comment: I've just tried this code,well,more specifically,I've tried the first chunck in a loop and it works marvelously

Comment: @nicochulo, I tried your code on my machine (Windows 7 Home Premium). It seems to work, even for the `startup` folder you mention. Investigating this oddity, I determined that having `Display the full path in the title bar (Classic theme only)`, under tools and folder options, UNCHECKED results in failure, but once checked it works! I haven't tried this with the `taskkill` command, but have been reading of issues with this depending on the OS you're using. All the best.

Comment: @AlbertFitzwilliamDigby Thanks for the answer! Even though the code Hackoo has proposed works, this knowledge might help me in the future